# Issue Setting CiviCRM up with Wordpress Multi-Site

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have a Wordpress multi-site installation in place that works fine and I have been trying to add CiviCRM to the multi-site but I am having problems when going through the documentation.

Now, I have installed CiviCRM on the main domain of the multisite and I have then followed the steps setup out in this documentation: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Multi+Site+Installation

Everything goes fine until I get to point 5.C and edit the civicrm.settings.php file. Once I edit this file and insert the subdomains for the sub sites, the CiviCRM tab on the main site returns a server 500 error. It is only when I revert back to the original settings file that CiviCRM is able to load again.

Now as I have followed the documentation exactly I am stuck for why this is happening, or have I missed something?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Check your `civicrm.settings.php` is valid after making those changes. It may be some small error has crept in and proving hard to spot.

```
php -l civicrm.settings.php
```

(This will require commandline access on the server, or copying the file somewhere you have CLI PHP installed.)